# Is it a way to set a class as delegate in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I want to assign a class to a delegate, but it raise an error: *Expected member name following '.'* How could I do it?

```
let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fr, managedObjectContext: Utility.managedObjectContext(), sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
frc.delegate = Utility.class
```

Comment: How would that work though? A delegate is an instance of a class. I'm not sure it would be possible to for this to happen.

Comment: In Objective-C I have done it several times. A class is also an object just like an instance of a class.

Comment: Are you sure? You're sure you haven't set a singleton or something like that as a delegate?

Comment: this works in Objective-C: `NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:[DBDownload class]];`

Comment: Try Utility.self instead of Utility.class

Comment: @Fogmeister I am with you here: never seen a class is used as a delegate.

Answer (score 2):

A class cannot be used as a delegate. A delegate has to be an instance of a class. What has not been instantiated cannot be referenced. What is not there cannot be used.

The example you are giving with `NSURLConnection` does not use a class as a delegate.

It uses a class that conforms to the protocol `NSURLConnectionDelegate` and creates an object of this class during initialization. The magic happens in the initialization of the `NSURLConnection` object.

This is something completely different then setting .delegate to an already existing object.

The setter does not create an object for you that it used for the protocol methods, but expect to be provided with an already instantiated object.

The same applies to Objective-C as well.

Check out http://www.iosnomad.com/blog/2014/8/6/swift-nsfetchedresultscontroller-trickery for examples how to use `NSFetchedResultsController` in a Swift class (well you would do it in Objective-C very similar)

Comment: Ah thanks for explaining I didn't know that nsurlconnection did that. But then I don't use that any more anyway. Lol.

Comment: Hi scythe42, quick question, how can I set delegate = self, if I cannot instantiate an object because it is a generic class which I don't have access to in the other class, yet I want the generics class to call a function in the other class, hence the need for delegate?